# Cannot load fixtures in Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, fixtures, symfony-3.4

I'm using the DoctrineFixturesBundle.  According to the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html), any class that extends `Fixture` will be automatically wired up so the console knows how to handle it.  However, despite my fixtures class extending `Fixture` (code below), I keep getting the following error:

> Could not find any fixture services to load.

If I attempt to wire up the service manually in my `services.yml` file with:

```
services:
    AppBundle\DataFixtures\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/DataFixtures/'
        tags: ['doctrine.fixture.orm']
```

I instead get:

> In FileLoader.php line 168:
>
> The file "../../src/AppBundle/DataFixtures" does not exist (in: /path/to/project/app/config) in /path/to/project/app/config/services.yml (which is being imported from "/path/to/project/app/config/config.yml").
>
> In FileLocator.php line 71:
>
> The file "../../src/AppBundle/DataFixtures" does not exist (in: /path/to/project/app/config).

The path to my data fixtures is `/path/to/project/src/DataFixtures`.  The actual class file (`AppFixtures.php`) is:

```
namespace AppBundle\DataFixtures;

use AppBundle\Entity\Category;
use AppBundle\Entity\Product;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class AppFixtures extends Fixture
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $em)
    {
        $category = new Category();

        $category->setName("Test Category")
            ->setSlug()
            ->setDescription("This is only for test purposes");

        $fabricProduct = new Product();

        $fabricProduct->setName("Test OldProduct")
            ->setCanonicalPrice(2.45)
            ->setHasSale(false)
            ->setCategory($category)
            ->setSlug()
            ->setNumberInStock(45.25);

        $em->persist($category);
        $em->persist($fabricProduct);
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

To preemptively answer the obvious questions, yes the bundle is registered correctly.  And my `services.yml` file has the default autowiring:

```
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        # automatically injects dependencies in your services
        autowire: true
        # automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        autoconfigure: true
        # this means you cannot fetch services directly from the container via $container->get()
        # if you need to do this, you can override this setting on individual services
        public: false
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  According to all the documentation I've found, this should be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it... with the way the default service wiring works in Symfony, it expects everything to be in the `src/AppBundle` directory.  My fixtures were in a directory outside of that one (yet, still in the project directory, obviously).  Moving my fixtures directory to be a child of `src/AppBundle` fixed it.